# Correct Syntax for Google's Remarketing Code in Slim for Ruby on Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to install some remarketing code in a slim partial and in testing, the output doesn't quite look right.

Here's the javascript I've been given:

```
<!-- Google Code for Remarketing Tag -->
<!--------------------------------------------------
Remarketing tags may not be associated with personally identifiable information or placed on pages related to sensitive categories. See more information and instructions on how to setup the tag on: http://google.com/ads/remarketingsetup
--------------------------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = my_id_here;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/my_id_here/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

and here's what I was about to convert it to (via HTML2Slim package in Sublime)

```
- if Rails.env.development?
    /! Google Code for Remarketing Tag
    /!
      | \------------------------------------------------
      | Remarketing tags may not be associated with personally identifiable information or placed on pages related to sensitive categories. See more information and instructions on how to setup the tag on: http://google.com/ads/remarketingsetup
      | \-------------------------------------------------
    javascript:
      /!*  */
      | var google_conversion_id = my_id_here;
      | var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
      | var google_remarketing_only = true;
      /!*  */
    script src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" type="text/javascript" 
    noscript
      div style="display:inline;" 
        img alt="" height="1" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/my_id_here/?guid=ON&amp;script=0" style="border-style:none;" width="1" /
```

When I run this in development, here's what outputs in the DOM

```
<!--Google Code for Remarketing Tag--><!--| \------------------------------------------------
| Remarketing tags may not be associated with personally identifiable information or placed on pages related to sensitive categories. See more information and instructions on how to setup the tag on: http://google.com/ads/remarketingsetup
| \--------------------------------------------------->
<script>
    /!*  */
    | var google_conversion_id = my_id_here;
    | var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    | var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /!*  */
</script>
<script src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" type="text/javascript"></script><noscript><div style="display:inline;"><img alt="" height="1" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/my_id_here/?guid=ON&amp;amp;script=0" style="border-style:none;" width="1" /></div></noscript>
```

All seems well except for a couple of things:

1. I lose the `/* <![CDATA[ */` and `/* ]]> */` lines (pretty sure Google will need those.
2. All script tags drop the `type="text/javascript"` attribute but I'm guessing this won't matter too much

So my question is, how do I ensure that `/* <![CDATA[ */` and `/* ]]> */` render with the slim-language OR is there a way to escape the language in this file and drop in a raw block of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just used the simple `|` to denote 'Verbatim Text'. It's like the most basic syntax rule of the Slim language.

Here's what the code ends up looking like:

```
javascript:
      | /* <![CDATA[ */
      | var google_conversion_id = my_id_here;
      | var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
      | var google_remarketing_only = true;
      | /* ]]> */
```

derp. Slim's super nice